# CPU/NET Leasehold model

Tags: cpu, net

Who can tell me about the leasing model of EOS, or where do you find the corresponding EOS code?

Comment: [`contracts/eosio.system/delegate_bandwidth.cpp`](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/905e7c85714aee4286fa180ce946f15ceb4ce73c/contracts/eosio.system/delegate_bandwidth.cpp)

Comment: This is the original mortgage leasing mode, and there is no REX related code at present

Comment: rex is not live and the interim solution is probably not on the master branch